# Concatenating a directory of html with windows batch, the path is echoed into the file. How do I stop the file name from being included?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, concatenation

I'm using a drag-n-drop batch script on Windows XP/7 to concatenate a direcotry of html files. I'm finding that part of the command is being echoed into the final concatenated file above the content of the file. How do I stop the the shell prompt, type and path from being included in my file?

bat script:

```
set inputdir=%~dpn1
set scriptroot=%~dp0
>"%scriptroot%concat.html" (for /r %inputdir% %%F in (*.html) do type "%%F")
```

output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\TMPUSER>type C:\test\test.html"
<html>
...
</html>
C:\Documents and Settings\TMPUSER>type C:\test\test2.html"
<html>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
```

Put this at the top of your script.

Answer (score 2):

If your program is a .bat file, write this at the first line:

```
@echo off
```

By default, the comands (and the working folder) are displayed:

```
C:\folder>echo hi
hi
```

To disable this, use **@echo off**, to enable it back, use **@echo on**.

Hope it helped!